# Error in setting up swagger in expressjs project

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

I have followed [this][1] link to add swagger to my existing project. I encountered the following error while setting up swagger. Any leads will be highly appreciated.

```
    :xxx\node_modules\swagger-node-express\Common\node\
    swagger.js:84
      self.appHandler.get(self.resourcePath.replace(self.formatString, self.jsonSuff
    ix), resourceListing);

   ^TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of null

  [1]: https://github.com/shawngong/Swagger-Node-Express-For-Existing-APIs
```

This error is popping out because of -

```
var applicationUrl = 'http://localhost:9000'; //application runs properly on this url
swagger.configure(applicationUrl, '1.0.0');//error here
```

Comment: `self.appHandler` is `null` - have you initialized it? Otherwise please update your question with some code of where it is implemented.

Comment: @k1dbl4ck - updated by code, please check

Comment: thank you. please see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the line of code in question [node-swagger-express](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node/blob/2.0.x/lib/swagger.js#L441) it seems as if you need to call :

```
swagger.setAppHandler(app);
```

Before the `configure` call.

I specifically see the maintainer of the project you are using (https://github.com/shawngong/Swagger-Node-Express-For-Existing-APIs) has a commit message related to `setAppHandler` in his last commit. Perhaps there is now an issue related to it.